# Why doesn't open (K)Ubuntu boot when my 2nd NVMe is attached? (Not dual boot)

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, acer, nvme

My laptop: Acer Predator Helios 300 PH512-52

My setup: 2 M2 NVMes, 1 is 256 GB and the other is 1 TB.

---

Yesterday, I have decided that I want to keep remove windows completely and continue with Linux. As I know that Linux isn't compatible with RST (and optane), I changed the SATA to AHCI (I don't care about windows so I didn't do the driver step in windows)

After that, I went through the installation normally, I choose entire disk my 256 GB which had windows previously (I could see listed my 2 NVMes, and I chose my 256 for installation)

After that, I couldn't login to Linux no matter what I do, my bios also was giving a blank screen with a white cursor on top.

After some trial and error, I noticed that when I remove my 1 TB NVMe, everything works normally whether bios or my linux boot. However, when I add it back in, I get a bootloop and my bios gets cracked again.

I started to do the basic diagnosis that I could think of:

1. Turned on and off secured boot.
2. Tried to go back to RST and back to AHCI Diagnosed my NVMe for bad sectors using badblocks in live CD.
3. Formatted my NVMe with `nvme-cli` in live CD
4. Tried to edit the grub boot and add `nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=5500`
5. Ran the boot-repair tool in live CD
6. Did a battery drain to rest the battery

Note that my NVMe gets recognized normally in my live CD and can write,read and copy to it. Also, it gets recognized on my 2nd laptop when plugged in, it was also recognized in Windows

I am out of ideas at the moment, and I like the challenge :D But it appears I am not up to it enough.

PS: Currently, I am trying to flash windows again and then reflash linux on AHCI directly.

Comment: The BIOS, after the POST, checks the disks in the BIOS specified order.  Upon finding a partition with the BOOT flag set, it boots from it, without checking. Boot your live CD, and use `gparted` to ensure none of the partitions on your "1 TB NVMe" has the BOOT flag set.

Comment: Already done, they don't have any boot flag